# Extract all elements of array with the given list of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have to extract all elements of array with the given list of coordinates and insert into 2*298808 as position given in while loop

How can I compress the code even more?

```
def arr_func(arr,selected_pixels_list): 

        rows = 2 
        m = 0 
        n = 0 
        i =0

        #Calculate the number of pixels selected 
        length_of_the_list = len(selected_pixels_list) 
        length_of_the_list = int(length_of_the_list/4)*4 
        cols = int(length_of_the_list/2) 
        result_arr = np.zeros((rows,cols)) 

        
        while(i<length_of_the_list): 
            result_arr[m,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i]] 
            result_arr[m,n+1] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+1]] 
            result_arr[m+1,n] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+2]] 
            result_arr[m+1,n+1] = arr[selected_pixels_list[i+3]] 
        
            i = i+4 
            m = 0 
            n = n+2 
        coordinate_data_list
        return result_arr
```

Comment: What do you mean by compressing your code and why do you want that?

Comment: This code will not execute. `coordinate_data_list` is undefined and does not make syntactic sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your code is managing a lot of variables and implementing some moderately complex index logic**. Sometimes that's necessary, but
sometimes it indicates that you've walked down an overly complex pathway. In
the rest of this discussion, I'll try to offer some intuition for building
up a simpler approach.

**We want to rearrange data into a list of two lists**. As I understand things,
our goal is sketched in the partial code below. For discussion purposes, I've
skipped the numpy part. Also note that I've simplified some of the variable
names (your current names strike me as excessively verbose in some cases).
Finally, I don't want to implement any index-based logic. If
possible, I just want to iterate over `pixels`. Note the top-down
problem-solving strategy: we write the top-level code we want to have
even though we don't know exactly how to achieve some of the details yet.

```
def arr_func(arr, pixels):
    result = [[], []]
    for p in pixels:
        # Get the value of arr[p] and stick it in the right spot
        # inside result. Specifically, we want to add 2 values to the
        # first inner list, then add 2 values to the second inner list,
        # toggling back and forth.
        ...
    return result
```

**How do we toggle back and forth**? To achieve the unusual toggling we can use
[itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle),
which creates an iterable representing an infinite cycle over some other
iterable -- in our case, the iterable `(0, 0, 1, 1)`, which is exactly how we
need to toggle between the inner lists.

```
from itertools import cycle

def arr_func(arr, pixels):
    result = [[], []]
    indexes = cycle((0, 0, 1, 1))
    for p in pixels:
        result[next(indexes)].append(arr[p])
    return result
```

**Next steps**. (1) Better names: give `arr` and `arr_func` substantive variable names, if
possible. (2) There might be a sneaky way to rearrange the data entirely in numpy, so
another reviewer might offer even better guidance.